# In Moodle find out programmatically the role of logged in user even if user changes login as

Tags: moodle

Suppose a teacher logs in for a course, I can programmatically find out the role of the logged in user as teacher, no problem

```
global $USER;
$context = context_course::instance($COURSE->id);
$roles = get_user_roles($context, $USER->id, false);
$role = key($roles);
$roleid = $roles[$role]->roleid;
```

Suppose the teacher chooses LOG IN AS a STUDENT, how do I find out the current role of the logged in user based on the logged in user id since it will always  show as TEACHER and not STUDENT ?

Basically if a TEACHER logs in as a STUDENT how to find out the role  **"logged in as"** of the logged in user ?

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['USER']->realuser)) {
    // Logged in as.
    $roles = get_user_roles($context, $_SESSION['USER']->realuser, false);
}
```